# How common are "la même ritournelle" and "le même son de cloche" in meaning "the same old story"?

Tags: traduction, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

Saying that *it's always the same old story* is quite common in English, and these are two ways I've come across of expressing it. From Google N-gram, neither seems very common-- *le même son de cloche* peaked in the 1940s and has been on the decline ever since (never promising) while *la même ritournelle* was never even as popular as that.

Are these very old-fashioned expressions, or still quite commonly used? Is there a more common way of expressing it nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sound a little old-fashioned. In casual speech, you're much more likely to hear “C'est toujours la même histoire”. Notice that you've got to drop the *old* as there's no way to put it in there.

Comment: +1 pour *la même histoire*. Il m'arrive cependant d'utiliser aussi *la même rengaine* qui, à mon sens, sous-entend le coté "old".

Comment: @Sinusoïde: Bonne remarque. C'est probablement un peu moins courant, mais ça s'entend parfois.

Comment: "no way to put it in there" -- I never thought about that, but can you not put an adjective between *même* and the noun? I suppose it's true I've never seen that formulation.